# Compare and Remove List Items using For Loop

Tags: c#

I have a Download List and an Exclude List.

I want to keep only `File2.zip` using a for loop.

However the loop doesn't work correctly and keeps both `File2.zip` and `File4.zip`.

http://rextester.com/UWCT32568

---

This is example code I want to apply to a larger project.

I do not want to use `download = download.Except(excluded).ToList();` in this case.

http://rextester.com/HBQZPC42707

---

```
List<string> download = new List<string>();
download.Add("File1.zip");
download.Add("File2.zip");
download.Add("File3.zip");
download.Add("File4.zip");
download.Add("File5.zip");

List<string> excluded = new List<string>();
excluded.Add("File1.zip");
// keep File2.zip
excluded.Add("File3.zip");
excluded.Add("File4.zip");
excluded.Add("File5.zip");


// Remove Excluded Files from Download List
//
int count = download.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // index out of range check
    if (download.Count() > i )
    {
        // Remove
        if (excluded.Contains(download[i]))
        {
            download.RemoveAt(i);
            download.TrimExcess();
        }
    }
}


// Display New Download List
//
download.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
```

---

Comment: Aside: If you're removing things, why not loop backwards so you don't need to include an out of range check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When removing, loop *backward*:
2. Use `HashSet<string>` which is more efficient for finding an item at

Implementation:

```
 // Items to remove: excluded.Contains(item) is more efficient if excluded is a HashSet<T>
 HashSet<string> excluded = new HashSet<string>() {
   "File1.zip",
   "File3.zip",
   "File4.zip",
   "File5.zip",  
 };

 for (int i = download.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
   if (excluded.Contains(download[i])) // Shall we remove i-th item?
     download.RemoveAt(i);             // If yes, remove it 

 // If you want to trim the list, do not do it within the loop, 
 // but remove all the required items and only then trim (once!) the list
 download.TrimExcess(); // Not necessary, but possible
```

**Edit:** In (*rare*) cases when you *have to* loop *forward* (e.g. if you have to remove the items in the order they were created) the loop is

```
 for (int i = 0; i < download.Count;)   // please, notice, no increment here
   if (excluded.Contains(download[i]))  // Shall we remove i-th item?
     download.RemoveAt(i)               // If yes, remove it
   else
     i += 1;                            // If no, inspect the next item
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this on my larger project now.

Answer (score 2):

You want to loop backwards when removing items:

```
//for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
for (int i=count-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    // index out of range check
    //if (download.Count() > i ) - No longer needed.
    //{
        // Remove
        if (excluded.Contains(download[i]))
        {
            download.RemoveAt(i);
            download.TrimExcess();
        }
    //}
}
```

After this change, it shows "File2.zip".

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this on my larger project now.